# NetLogo: How to import 2 column adjacency list to create graph?

Tags: matrix, netlogo

I have a txt file, where the directed links of the desired graphs are stored. First and second column refer to the ID of the nodes: "1 122" means that there is a link betweed node 1 and node 122.

```
1 122
1 2
2 1
2 1000
...
```

My questions:

a) Is it possible to import a txt file like this to NetLogo and create a graph with it?

b) The file has got more than 100,000 lines. Would this cause a problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy actually!

```
turtles-own [ node-id ]

to import-graph [ filename ]
  file-open filename
  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let source get-or-create-node file-read
    let target get-or-create-node file-read
    ask source [ create-link-to target ]
  ]
end

to-report get-or-create-node [ id ]
  let nodes turtles with [ node-id = id ]
  if not any? nodes [
    crt 1 [ set node-id id set nodes turtle-set self ]
  ]
  report one-of nodes
end
```

[`file-read`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#file-read) does the work of actually reading the numbers out of the file.

One down side of this approach is that it has to search through all the turtles to find the turtle with a particular id. This can be slow when loading graphs with a very large number of nodes. In those cases, you can use the [table](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/arraystables.html) extension to maintain a table mapping node ids to turtles.

Note that for several common formats for graph and network files, you can use the [network](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html) extension to import the file. The next of version NetLogo will have support for several more filetypes (though not the one you have here).

As for 100,000: that is fairly large, not because of the size of the file, but because that's 100,000 links in your model if there's one per line. Moving turtles around will likely be slow, but querying the network (e.g. with the network extension) should still be pretty fast.